# Clarification of [cinch] tag wiki entry

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4232198) came up in my edit reviews. I skipped it because I'm not familiar with the subject; but the new edited entry for [cinch](/questions/tagged/cinch) is:

> Cinch may refer to an open source MVVM framework for .NET available in a WPF and Silverlight flavor or a ruby based IRC bot framework.

The IRC bot part was added (to me that seems a bit minor but I'm not familiar enough with it to judge).

The real point here is: The .NET framework and the IRC bot framework are two completely unrelated things. It doesn't seem to me like they belong in the same tag. Perhaps the tag should be split (it's such a minor tag, though), or one should be removed. I'm bringing this up in hopes that somebody more knowledgeable on the subject might take a look at it.

Note that one reviewer did reject with the reason: "This cinch tag does not refer to what you suggest; you may create a new tag for that usage if necessary."

Post count in tag is only 18: 2 refer to the IRC framework (both asked by same user; note: not the user who updated the wiki), 16 to the .NET API. It's a pretty low usage tag anyways, maybe it should just go away.

Comment: The tag should be split to remove the ambiguity.  `cinch-mvvm-framework` and `cinch-bot`?